# How to get the image url from a css string.

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am having an issue where I am trying to get the image url from the string.

An example of a string would be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 47.938em) { 
  .screen__start__play-btn::after { content: " "; display: block; height: 25px; position: relative; width: 100%; background-image: url(http://localhost:8080/_client/images/mouseover-line.png); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
} - as a string
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var cssPropertiesObj = {
    mediaQuery: ['47.938em'],//media query array function get these results
    css: ['@media only screen and (max-width: 47.938em) { 
      .screen__start__play-btn::after { content: " "; display: block; height: 25px; position: relative; width: 100%; background-image: url(http://localhost:8080/_client/images/mouseover-line.png); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
    }'] // get css of each media query
};


function removeUnwantedMedia(mediaQuery, css, arrayLength) {
    var startString = css.indexOf('url(');
    var endString = css.indexOf(')');

    if(css.indexOf('url(') === -1) {
        cssPropertiesObj.mediaQuery.splice(arrayLength, 1);
        cssPropertiesObj.css.splice(arrayLength, 1);
    } else {
        css.substring(startString, endString);
        console.log(css.substring(startString, endString));
    }
    console.log(css);
}
var i;
for(i = 0; i < cssPropertiesObj.mediaQuery.length; i++){
    removeUnwantedMedia(cssPropertiesObj.mediaQuery[i], cssPropertiesObj.css[i], i);
}
```

What I am expecting the cssPropertiesObj.css[0] is to be equal to 'http://localhost:8080/_client/images/mouseover-line.png' without all the css jargon.

Is this possible to do in JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/background-image: url\((.*)\)\;/` regex to get background image url from string:

```
var matches = cssPropertiesObj.css[0].match(/background-image: url\((.*)\)\;/);
if (matches) {
  cssPropertiesObj.css[0] = matches[1]
}
```